# Storing files on SD card in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, sd-card, android-sdcard, data-storage

I would like to store a file on the SD card.  According to the Android docs,  `SharedPreference` can help to retrieve key-value pairs of primitive data types. However, it stores files in the internal storage.

Is there a class with similar functionality to `SharedPreference` but which can store a file on the SD card?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to check if the SD card is accessable with:

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Do not forget to put below in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can then use something like this:

```
File file = new File(root, "/sdcard/test.txt");             
FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(file);             
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fwriter);             
out.write("Hello world");             
out.close();
```

Comment: @King Wu
If this solved the problem, them please mark the answer as correct.
Thx.

Comment: Thx Lars. Do any class can help to store a value with key in SD?

Comment: Hi for small saves i would recommend the class Sharedpreferences.
You can also use this class to store values, minuspoint is that saved values will be deleted after your app is removed.